# When switching between sound devices, playback gets much faster

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card

I've recently acquired a Asus Xonar DX soundcard.

Attached to it are speakers and headphones. When switching between the playback devices with the Volume Mixer at system tray, I get a much faster playback of sound files. Normal voices sound like chipmunks.

I need to restart the Windows Audio service to fix this. Do you know a more permanent solution?

Comment: Latest drivers installed?

Comment: Yes, the latest drivers are installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem:

The sample rate in control panel/sound has to be the same as the sample rate in Asus Xonar Audio Center. In this case I had 44,1 kHz in Windows and 96 kHz in the Xonar Audio Center.